# fatal error: QtMultimediaWidgets/QtMultimediaWidgets: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

Trying to run 'make' for a QT project on Ubuntu and got this error:

```
fatal error: QtMultimediaWidgets/QtMultimediaWidgets: No such file or directory
```

How can I download this package?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a QT 5.x header, in ubuntu you should get [QT5 development files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqt5).

Comment: Maybe by looking for the file in their [package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) engine? Seems like a multimedia development file, a further find will tell.